# найти значение конкретного инпута в определенном блоке в цикле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно найти значение конкретного инпута в определенном блоке. 
`$("div[data-type-diagnosis]")` - выдает массив из четырех элементов, в каждом из которых есть свои вложенные и не вложенные элементы. Мне нужно в каждом из этих 4-х элементов найти инпуты которые содержат

`var yy = $(".input-yy").val();
 var mm = $(".input-mm").val();
 var dd = $(".input-dd").val();
 var hh = $(".input-hh").val();
 var mi = $(".input-mi").val();`

Есть такой код:

```
var block = $("div[data-type-diagnosis]");

for (x = 0; x < block.length; x++) {
    var yy = block[x].find(".input-yy").val();
    var mm = block[x].find(".input-mm").val();
    var dd = block[x].find(".input-dd").val();
    var hh = block[x].find(".input-hh").val();
    var mi = block[x].find(".input-mi").val();
}
```

B этом коде ругается что find не является функцией. Но как же мне найти тогда в каждом из этих четерых блоков значения нужных мне элементов и изменить их на нужные мне значения ?

Comment: `$(block[x]).find(...` или `block.eq(x).find(...` - `block[x]` возвращает DOM элемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё работает правильно, нужно только обращаться как к jQuery объектам:

```
var block = $("div[data-type-diagnosis]");
for (x = 0; x < block.length; x++) {
    var yy = $(block[x]).find(".input-yy").val();
    var mm = $(block[x]).find(".input-mm").val();
    var dd = $(block[x]).find(".input-dd").val();
    var hh = $(block[x]).find(".input-hh").val();
    var mi = $(block[x]).find(".input-mi").val();
}
```